# BigDecimal retornar sempre positivo

Tags: java, matemática

Gostaria de saber se é possível retornar positivo o resultado de uma subtração em BigDecimal que o primeiro valor é menor que o segundo valor.

Segue exemplo:

```
BigDecimal subTotalPorDebitos = 6131.95; 

BigDecimal subTotalPorCreditos = 8553.99; 

BigDecimal totalSaldoDevedorARecolher = BigDecimal.ZERO; 

totalSaldoDevedorARecolher = subTotalPorDebitos.subtract(subTotalPorCreditos);
```

Resultado: -2.422,04 (Eu gostaria que esse valor fosse transformado em positivo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando o método `abs` da classe [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> Retorna um BigDecimal cujo valor é o valor absoluto deste BigDecimal e cuja escala é this.scale().

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
BigDecimal subTotalPorDebitos = new BigDecimal(6131.95);
BigDecimal subTotalPorCreditos = new BigDecimal(8553.99);
BigDecimal totalSaldoDevedorARecolher = BigDecimal.ZERO;

totalSaldoDevedorARecolher = subTotalPorDebitos.subtract(subTotalPorCreditos);
System.out.println("Valor da subtração: "+ totalSaldoDevedorARecolher);
System.out.println("Valor absoluto: "+totalSaldoDevedorARecolher.abs());
```

Resultado:

```
Valor da subtração: -2422.0399999999999636202119290828704833984375
Valor absoluto: 2422.0399999999999636202119290828704833984375
```